# Visual Studio generating exe even though nothing has changed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, build

I ran into this issue where each time I switch between Release and Debug configuration of a C# solution and do a build, Visual Studio always seem to generate a new version of the executable even though neither the dependencies or the source code has changed. Say for example I have 2 projects in a solution, Project A (generates an exe) and Project B (generates a dll) and project A has a project reference to Project B. Switching configuration and building Project A always generate a new version of the executable even though nothing has changed.

In some of our solutions, we modified the csproj such that the HintPath points to something like "../../bin/$(Configuration)/someLibrary.dll" and this triggers the same build issue. I found fixing the reference to a absolute path(e.g. C:\Tools\bin\Release\someLibrary.dll) fixes the build issue.

Wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue and has a solution for it?

Thuan Seah Tan

Comment: I would stay away from absolute paths.  It is very difficult to ensure that everyone has things installed in identical locations on their PCs ... but if your 3rd-party DLLs are under version control, ../../3rdparty/ will (almost) always work, whether your project root folder is C:\Work or C:\Documents and Settings\David\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010 Projects\.

Comment: Turn up the build log level and see what it says. I've seen VS be entirely convinced things have to always rebuild for no apparent reason, but typically the higher-level logs have a suggestion.